# Java Swing - set panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm quite new to Swing, and I'm programming an application with NetBeans' UI designer.
Now I have an JPanel called "editorPanel", and it must be able to display multiple things. (so, sometimes it has to display an image, and sometimes it has to display a text editor)

I have made separate panels for this, so say I'd have a JPanel called ImagePanel and one called TextPanel. It has to switch easily between them, so I tried this:

```
editorPanel = new ImagePanel();
```

But that didn't work.

So, what I want to do, is set an empty panel to a defined panel.
How can I make this work?

Comment: Post some code instead of describing what you have done with english words. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` to flip between 2 or more other panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to achieve your goal is to using a card layout and switching panels accordingly.

You ca get some idea on how card layout stuff is working in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)